# Is there any self complementary graph of order 5 other than C5

Tags: graph-theory

The concept of a self-complementary graph as I learned is, a graph that is isomorphic to its complement is called self-complement. I have some examples in mind of the self-complementary graph of order five but I am confused about, how can we find a self-complementary graph of order five other than copies of C5. Kindly give me the answer with an example.

Comment: There are not that many graphs on five vertices - you can just make the list and see :)

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of questions, I like to simply use sage with geng. Try this code

```
for g in graphs.nauty_geng("{0} -c".format(5)):
    if g.is_isomorphic(g.complement()):
        g.show()
```

Yielding to

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze this question as follows: Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is a self-complementary graph of order $5$ and let $\overline{G}=(V,E')$ denote its complement.

First, since $G\cong\overline{G}$, we have $|E|=|E'|$. Besides, it is clear that $G\cup\overline{G}=K_5$ and $E\cap E'=\emptyset$, so $$|E|+|E'|=\binom{5}{2}=10.$$ Thus, $|E|=|E'|=5$.

Now you consider the degree sequence $d_1\leq d_2\leq d_3\leq d_4\leq d_5$ in $G$. The degree sequence in $\overline{G}$ is $$4-d_5\leq4-d_4\leq 4-d_3\leq 4-d_2\leq 4-d_1.$$ Again, since $G\cong\overline{G}$, we must have $4-d_5=d_1$, $4-d_4=d_2$ and $4-d_3=d_3$. That is, it yields $$d_1+d_5=d_2+d_4=4$$ and $d_3=2$. Besides, $d_1>0$, for $d_1=0$ implies $d_5=4$. It is impossible for a graph of order $5$ containing both an isolated vertex (degree $0$) and a vertex adjacent to all others (degree $4$). Note that $d_2\leq d_3=2$ and consider the following cases:

1. Suppose $d_2=1$. Then $d_4=4-d_2=4-1=3$. Since $1\leq d_1\leq d_2=1$, we must have $d_1=1$. Thus, the degree sequence of $G$ is $1,1,2,3,3$. This is precisely the first graph shown in David's answer.
2. Suppose $d_2=2$. Then $d_2=d_3=d_4=2$. Of course, if $d_1=2$, then $G$ is $C_5$. What if $d_1=1$? As we can see, the degree sequence now becomes $1,2,2,2,3$. There are two graphs of order $5$ possessing such sequence, but they are neither self-complementary nor isomorphic to each other.

In general, all the examples are displayed in David's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Self Complementary Graphs means that the number of vertices and degree sequence of each graph is equal. Also, addition of
self complementary graphs result in a complete graph with $ \frac {n(n-1)}{2} $ edges.

Using the formula

$$e(G) \;=\; \frac {n(n-1)}{4},$$

(self complement graph verification), we can see that $e = 5$.

Then, using the formula

$$n(G) = {{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \choose e} = {10 \choose 5} = 252,$$

(or simply by looking), if one complement ($G_n$) has 5 edges then ($K_n$) will have $2*5 = 10$ edges; thus giving us $10 \choose 5$.

Out of which i believe one half is the complement of the other. So genuinely you would get only 126 pairs of self-complementary graphs in a 5-vertice graph.

Tadaa!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks! @AnotherUser

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what self-complementary graphs are. (And "pairs of self-complementary graphs" is nonsense; if a graph is self-complementary, it's isomorphic to its own complement, so there's no "pair" to talk about.) The quantity $126$ counts the number of pairs of complementary graphs on a labeled $5$-vertex set; in most such pairs, neither graph will be self-complementary.